# How to restrict selected value repetition in dynamic drop down in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

Please see this image.

[image]

I have this dynamic drop down selection in my jsp page. When i need to update my form i am displaying selected value and then rest of the dynamic drop down values.

This is the code i have written

```
<%      
   List<CreateJobOrderBean> marketingemplist = cju.getMarkeringEmpList(emp_branch_id);
       CreateJobOrderBean marketingempbean = null;
    %>

<% 
  String marketing_fullname cju.getMarkering_Fullname(joborderdata.getAssignedmarketingemail());
%>


<select class="form-field" style="height: 24px;width:234px;" name="assignedmarketing">
             <option value="<%=(joborderdata!=null?(joborderdata.getAssignedmarketingemail() != null?joborderdata.getAssignedmarketingemail():""):"")%>" ><%=marketing_fullname%></option>
             <option value="">------Select------</option>
             <% for(int i=0; i<marketingemplist.size();i++){
                        marketingempbean= marketingemplist.get(i);
                        if(marketingempbean!=null){ %>
                        <option value="<%=marketingempbean.getAssignedmarketingemail()%>"><%=marketingempbean.getAssignedmarketingfullname()%></option>
                        <%}}%>
      </select>
```

What i need is, it should not repeat the selected value in drop down. It should display only once in the drop down.

I think you got my point.
Please help me.

Comment: what is the purpose of the first option tag(above ---Select---)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below script on below event

**HTML**

```
<select name="assignedmarketing" onclick="return removeItem();" >
```

**Jquery**

```
function removeItem()
{
//alert('Hello');
 $("[name=assignedmarketing] option").each(function(i){
        $(this).show();
    });
var index = $('[name=assignedmarketing]').get(0).selectedIndex;
$('[name=assignedmarketing] option:eq(' + index + ')').hide();

}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [jQuery tagator](https://github.com/FaroeMedia/tagator) will help you. Instead of adding values into drop down, add those values in `Javascript Array` and use these tagator plugin. It will do the add/remove the values automatically. See the [Demo](http://opensource.faroemedia.com/tagator/) here. Following simple script is all you need,

```
$('#input_tagator1').tagator({
     autocomplete: ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh'],
     useDimmer: true
});
```

Hope this helps you.